# how do i read totp generated by the totp secret engine in hashicorp vault using hashi-vault-js node module.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashicorp-vault, vault, totp

```
`vault
    // .readKVSecret(api_token, "63ab53521ce9dfe4ed6fad73", "", "iam-users")
    .readKVSecret(api_token, "", "", 'totp/sms/code/my-key')
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("**********data",data);
    });
```

by using above method i can read the secrets but what I should do if I want to read totp?